# How much film do I need (in feet/meters)?

Tags: film

I'm shooting 3-perf 35mm @ 24 fps. How many feet of film do I need if I'm shooting one hour?

Is there a good site/app for calculating this?

Comment: There are 3600 seconds in one hour so 24*3600 = 86.400 frames

Comment: This may be off-topic since it's regarding motion, not still photography.

Comment: Per discussion on meta this seems rather off-topic here. You might want to participate on Video a Film production site proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2797/video-and-film-production

Answer (score 5, accepted):

4,050 feet of film.

Kodak makes a free app for iOS called "KODAK Cinema Tools" which has a film calculator, among other features.

http://motion.kodak.com/US/en/motion/Tools/Mobile/index.htm

For reference:

- 8mm = 80.0 frames per foot
- Super 8 = 72.0 frames per foot
- 16mm = 40.0 frames per foot
- 35mm 2-perf = 32.0 frames per foot
- 35mm 3-perf = 21.3 frames per foot
- 35mm = 16.0 frames per foot
- 65mm = 12.8 frames per foot